# Use Flexbox to update from Column to Row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

**WHAT I WANT IS: MONTHS TO BE FROM LEFT TO RIGHT having JAN FEB MAR in the first ROW.**

```
JAN    FEB    MAR
APR    MAY    JUN
```

Encountering Problem in updating datepicker months in `react-datepicker`. Below image
shows 4 months in each row. Also, the months seems to be out of the allocaoted
width `309px`. Trying to fit the months boxes within the allocated space having
3 months in a single row.

Library in used: react-datepicker;

Though fits into the box, however, the alignment of months is not correct.
The requirement is to have

```
JAN    FEB    MAR
APR    MAY    JUN
...
```

After doing few tweaks, I can get the following. I'd appreciate your help on the requirement **i.e., Months to be displayed from left to right having 3 months in one Row.**

```
.react-datepicker__month-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; //-->updated
}

.react-datepicker__month {
  // margin: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;   //-->Updated
  margin:auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**BROWSERS ELEMENTS**
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: So After updating you got what you wanted ?. what help do you need on this ?

Comment: @ShankajaAroshana Months to be displayed from left to right having 3 months in one Row. JAN FEB MAR to be on first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [my example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-curran-6m9drn), I have tried to make it as you described

Basically what I did was to use this css code:

```css
.react-datepicker__month-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.react-datepicker__month-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.react-datepicker__month {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1; /* Use flex instead of flex-basis */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 2px; /* Add padding to avoid months sticking together */
}

.react-datepicker__month .react-datepicker__month-text,
.react-datepicker__month .react-datepicker__quarter-text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.6rem 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import "./flatpicker.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      dateFormat="MM/yyyy"
      showMonthYearPicker
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and for your Css try This:
remove `display:column` from your `.react-datepicker__month-wrapper` element and add it to `.react-datepicker__month`

More info: [Link](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-month-picker)

Answer (score 1):

### Do the folowing:

1. Use `flex-wrap: wrap` on `react-datepicker__month` so that it wraps.
2. Remove `flex-direction: column;` from `react-datepicker__month-wrapper`.
3. Use `showThreeColumnMonthYearPicker`

#### 1.

```
.react-datepicker__month {
  // margin: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* NEW */
}
```

#### 2.

```
.react-datepicker__month-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */ /* NEW */
}
```

#### 3.

```
export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePicker
        ref={ref}
        showMonthYearPicker
        showThreeColumnMonthYearPicker /* NEW */
        minViewMode="months"
        dateFormat="MMM-yyyy"
        excludeDates={[
          1661990400000, 1664582400000, 1667260800000, 1672531200000,
        ]}
        onChange={(e) => {}}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a div that wraps every 4 month with a class called `.react-datepicker__month-wrapper`.

[image]
Visit [`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wildflower-8nx77l?file=/src/flatpicker.css)

The above layout could be easily get by change code like this

Change `showFourColumnMonthYearPicker` to `showThreeColumnMonthYearPicker`

## Finally Code Should Look Like

```
   <DatePicker
        ref={ref}
        showMonthYearPicker
        showThreeColumnMonthYearPicker  // <= change this line
        minViewMode="months"
        dateFormat="MMM-yyyy"
        onChange={(e) => {}}
      />
```

```
.react-datepicker__month-container {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.react-datepicker__month-wrapper{
   display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}

.react-datepicker__month {
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.react-datepicker__month .react-datepicker__month-text,
.react-datepicker__month .react-datepicker__quarter-text {
  text-align: left;
  padding:0.6rem 2.4rem;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```